# Fading the image border in an imageview

Tags: android, android-layout, bitmap, android-imageview

I need to add a fading effect on a `ImageView`.
In my situation I have a `RelativeLayout`, the relative background in yellow and in the center of that background there is a `ImageView`. Now I need to apply a fade affect on the edge of the `ImageView`. Is this possible? (`Android api 11+`)

I tried:

```
android:requiresFadingEdge="horizontal"
android:fadingEdge="horizontal"
android:fadingEdge="vertical"
android:fadingEdgeLength="40px"
```

but doesn't work..

[image]

This is an example of what I want. Like you can see the **top and the left** are fading, the right and bottom edge, instead, are not fading..

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Any workaround on this issue ?

Answer (score 4):

Override methods in ImageView as written below:

```
private float FadeStrength = 1.0f;
private int FadeLength = 40px;

@Override
protected float getTopFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return FadeStrength;
}

@Override
protected float getBottomFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return FadeStrength;
}

@Override
protected float getLeftFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return FadeStrength;
}

@Override
protected float getRightFadingEdgeStrength() {
    return FadeStrength;
}
```

And on initialization of view add lines:

```
setFadingEdgeLength(FadeLength);
setVerticalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this work around: Don't need to extend ImageView

```
imageView.scrollTo(1,0);
imageView.setHorizontalFadingEdgeEnabled(true);
imageView.setFadingEdgeLength(40);
```